# Best proof of Artin approximation?

Tags: deformation-theory, intuition

I'm trying to learn deformation theory, where the algebraic Artin approximation theorem is crucial. However, the proofs I've seen* seem to go like:

1. Keep reducing the theorem until one is in a position to use ideas from the analytic Artin approximation theorem.
2. Mimick the proof of the analytic Artin approximation theorem.

Both steps are somewhat long and the second part is quite algebraic, and leave me with the feeling that I don't really understand why the result is true, even in special cases (for instance, after some of the reductions in step 1).

- Is there a cleaner proof around now?
- How should one should think about the result/proof to make things clearer?

Perhaps it's necessarily convoluted, but given how important a result it is it would be nice for something better.

---

*Both Artin's original paper ''Algebraic approximation of structures of complete local rings'' and Bosch's book ''Neron models'' prove it like this.